# PHP и mssql, как экранировать спецсимволы?

Tags: php, sql-server, безопасность

Здравствуйте! Недавно возникла задача обезопасить sql запросы к бд **mssql**. Появилась проблема: функция `mysql_real_escape_string()` не рабит для нее, а pdo использовать не есть возможно. В интернете почему-то четкого ответа на этот вопрос нет, единственное что нашел это: "...чтобы экранировать кавычку в MS SQL нужно перед ней поставить еще одну кавычку – и все! То есть вместо ‘ должно быть ”...". Возможно ли такое решение?

Comment: В инете уже давно есть ответ на этот вопрос и не только - это [использование PDO][1].

   [1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/

Comment: Забыл уточнить: PDO использовать невозможно по ряду причин

Answer (score 1):

[pack/unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574821/815386)

```
function mssql_escape($data) {
    if(is_numeric($data))
        return $data;
    $unpacked = unpack('H*hex', $data);
    return '0x' . $unpacked['hex'];
}

mssql_query('
    INSERT INTO sometable (somecolumn)
    VALUES (' . mssql_escape($somevalue) . ')
');
```

суть в следующем, все что не цифры паковать в hex, hex вставлять в базу.

Answer (score -1):

Что значит "не робит" `mysql_real_escape_string`?
Например, в запрос ниже можно сунуть все что угодно и ничего страшного никогда не произойдет

```
$res =mysql_query("UPDATE `table` 
                           SET `login`='". mysql_real_escape_string($login) ."'
                           WHERE `id`=". (int)$id );
```

И не нужно никакие символы фильтровать. Пусть они себе в базе сидят. Главное - обрамлять апострофами и обрабатывать функцией mysql_real_escape_string() непосредственно в самом запросе.

Comment: @leonoff, а не скажите, как функция работающая только после подключения к MySQL будет работать c MSSQL?

Comment: Надо сразу говорить, что вы имели в виду "кастрированную" sql)) Посмотрите это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146546/mysql-real-escape-string-alternative-for-sql-server

Comment: насколько я понял, чтобы экранировать кавычку в MS SQL нужно перед ней поставить еще одну кавычку – и все?

Comment: или будет оптимальным такое решение?:`
function mssql_escape($str)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $str= stripslashes($str);
    }
    return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}`

Comment: Да. Вы правильно поняли. Кавычка экранируется ее повторением. Т.е. надо ставить не \, а просто повторить кавычку. А по поводу оптимального решения - это уж думать вам. Я просто показал некоторые готовые решения, которые можно "точить" под себя.

Comment: кстати, давно интересно было: опасны только кавычки ведь в запросах? или есть еще символы какие?

Comment: Если кавычки были бы опасными(как и любые другие символы) - их не было бы на клавиатуре. Вы чем-то не тем забиваете голову. Главное, запомнить, что все числовые параметры должны быть приведены к нужному типу, а все остальные параметры должны быть обработаны функцией mysql_real_escape_string(в вашем случае использовать другую функцию) и заключены в кавычки. Так же не помещать в запрос управляющие структуры и идентификаторы, введенные пользователем, а заранее прописывать в скрипте список возможных вариантов, и выбирать только из них.А еще лучше использовать PDO.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо большое за помощь! Удачи Вам!